# How to Autoscroll listbox to bottom wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox , I add items dynamically to the listbox.

I want the listbox to autoscroll to the last item added.

I used

```
List<string> ItemsList = new List<string>

public void InsertItem(string newItem)
    {
        ItemsList.Add(status);
        if (ItemsList.Count > MaxSize)
        {
            ItemsList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        lb.Items.Refresh();
        lb.SelectedIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1;
        lb.ScrollIntoView(status);
    }
```

but this works only before my application is initialized (i.e I added some items before the application starts)

But after the application has started if I try adding items,the scroll bar is not auto scrolling to the last added item

Could any one tell solution for this

Comment: will need some of your relevant code to see where you might be going wrong

Comment: see if this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337822/wpf-listbox-scroll-to-end-automatically

Answer (score 2):

This has turned out to be quite a mission actually, because the ScrollIntoView only works the first time it is called. Every other call after that will not work for some reason.

The way around this, would be to find the "ScrollInfo" of the listbox and set the scroll value. See example below

```
    public static void AutoScrollToCurrentItem(ListBox listBox, int index)
    {
        // Find a container
        UIElement container = null;
        for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
        {
            container = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as UIElement;
            if (container != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (container == null) 
            return;

        // Find the ScrollContentPresenter
        ScrollContentPresenter presenter = null;
        for (Visual vis = container; vis != null && vis != listBox; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
            if ((presenter = vis as ScrollContentPresenter) != null)
                break;
        if (presenter == null) 
            return;

        // Find the IScrollInfo
        var scrollInfo =
            !presenter.CanContentScroll ? presenter :
            presenter.Content as IScrollInfo ??
            FirstVisualChild(presenter.Content as ItemsPresenter) as IScrollInfo ??
            presenter;

        // Find the amount of items that is "Visible" in the ListBox
        var height = (container as ListBoxItem).ActualHeight;
        var lbHeight = listBox.ActualHeight;
        var showCount = (int)(lbHeight / height) - 1;

        //Set the scrollbar
        if (scrollInfo.CanVerticallyScroll)
           scrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(index - showCount);
    }

    private static DependencyObject FirstVisualChild(Visual visual)
    {
        if (visual == null) return null;
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual) == 0) return null;
        return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, 0);
    }
```

The way to use the above code can be like this:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("New Item");
        AutoScrollToCurrentItem(listBox1, listBox1.Items.Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wish I had enough points to comment on your question. How is your ItemsList connected to your ListBox? After you start your application, can you manually scroll down to the new items?

Most likely you binded ItemsList to ListBox. If so, I suggest you change `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>` so that ListBox can automatically update itself.

[ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if u can update listbox automatically then use ObservableCollection.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _source  = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and your insert method:

```
private void Insert(string item)
      {
         _source.Add(item);

         lb.SelectedIndex = _source.Count - 1;
         lb.ScrollIntoView(ListBox.SelectedItem);
      }
```