# How to bind StackPanel Children from a ViewModel?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

New to Silverlight.  I'm working on a chat application where new chat messages are added to the bottom of a list.  I had a working version that used as StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer and then in some code behind used StackPanel.Children.Add().

I'm trying to convert this to a View-ViewModel approach, and I can't figure out how to bind the Children of the StackPanel to any collection property.  I've tried this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollMessages" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnlMessages" Orientation="Vertical" Children="{Binding Path=ExampleTBs}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

where ExampleTBs is a collection of TextBlocks created in code.  This fails XAML parsing, the Children property isn't bindable in this way.

Is the approach of binding to the StackPanel itself fixable?  Should I be using a different container type?  I saw another question where the guy created the entire StackPanel in code and then used a ContentPresenter...

Bottom line, I'd like to find a way to databind my view to a viewmodel using something like a StackPanel as a container where successive items will be added to the container over time.  Best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=VS.95).aspx) (or any other [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28VS.95%29.aspx)) and bind the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=VS.95).aspx) property to an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, this works, except for scrolling to the bottom upon adding a new item.  Off the top of your head, do you know of a ViewModelly way of doing this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006729/wpf-listbox-scroll-when-item-added

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use a `StackPanel`? If you use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(VS.95).aspx) instead, this still presents each chat message in a vertical list, and also allows for binding of the data.