# List Box Controls in Visual Studio to Auto-scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am working on a WPF main window and I am using a list box, and I want the list box to auto-scroll whenever new data is added. I used the `ListBoxBehavior` class in the chosen answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006729/how-can-i-have-a-listbox-auto-scroll-when-a-new-item-is-added/2007072), and I added the following namespaces for the that class in my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Also, in my XAML, I added the following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="IncomingData" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}" lb:ListBoxBehavior.ScrollOnNewItem="true"/>
```

However, I am getting the following three errors in my XAML code regarding that line, and they are as following:

1. `Error XDG0006    The namespace prefix "lb" is not defined`.
2. `Error    XDG0008 ListBoxBehavior is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project`.
3. `Error    XLS0415 The attachable property    'ScrollOnNewItem' was not found in type 'ListBoxBehavior'`.

I tried creating an object of a `ListBox` type `ListBox lb = new ListBox();` in the `ListBoxBehavior` class, but that didn't change the situation. Also, `ScrollOnNewItem` already exists in the class, so why is it not identifying it?
Is there a missing step that I should have done?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define the lb namespace before using it.

at the top of your xaml file you ought to see xmlns:x="...". notice you are using it with x:Name.

same goes for lb. you need to define xmlns:lb="...". intellisense should help you fill in the "...".

notice xmlns means xml namespace.

that ought to clear up all 3 errors.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and I set the namespace for lb to be as follows: ```xmlns:lb="DataViewer.ListBoxBehavior"``` such that DataViewer is the namespace that has the class ListBoxBehavior, MainWindow.xaml, and the code behind it in C#. However, that cleared only the first error regarding the prefix, and the other two are still there. Is it wrong howI defined the namespace, or should I define it in another way?

Comment: the type is ListBoxBehavior, and it is a member of the namespace DataViewer, so it's rather like `xmlns:dv="DataViewer"` which you'd then reference the behavior like `dv:ListBoxBehavior.ScrollOnNewItem="true"`. i guess the format's like `namespace:Type.Property="value"`

Comment: Now all errors have been fixed except a new one that appeared after I declared the namespace ```xmlns:lb="DataViewer"```  which visual studio has automatically set it to ```xmlns:lb="clr-namespace:DataViewer"``` The error is the following: The name "ListBoxBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DataViewer" I think the issue here is that Visual Studui isn't recognizing the ListBoxBehavior class within the namespace. It was already set to Compile when I checked the Configuration Manager. However, thanks a lot for your help.